# Using only html, how can I position an image behind header text?

Tags: html, sakai

I am working with Sakai and want to put header text in front of a banner image to make the lesson more accessible for voiceover users. The only problem is that Sakai 10.5 does not work well with CSS, so it has to be HTML only. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: with just html, not possible. you need css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a text reader to read the header text but not necessarily show it.

I'm guessing this is for accesibiliy.

http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#basics

Eg.

```
<img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome to Lesson 1" />
```

And the voiceover users will hear "Welcome to Lesson 1".